# Add a new favorite to Edge by URL

Tags: bookmarks, microsoft-edge

In Edge, is it possible to add a new favorite (aka bookmark) by its URL **without having to visit the URL**?

The reason why you would want to do this is because a URL does not necessarily resolve to a page on the internet.

In Internet Explorer, this is as simple as adding a new internet shortcut to the `%USERPROFILE%\Favorites` directory. The Edge browser seems to ignore the Favorites directory.

I'm not interested in answers that describe workarounds like importing bookmarks from IE.

Comment: Edge has its own favorite directory.  Works exactly like the IE favorite folder though

Comment: @Ramhound don't be selfish, tell us the directory path

Answer (score 1):

Looks like edit capability is on the way.  Per

https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/platform/issues/4368862/

Dirk F. ‎Jun‎ ‎22‎, ‎2017

https://blogs.windows.com/windowsexperience/2017/06/21/announcing-windows-10-insider-preview-build-16226-pc

“Edit URL for Favorites: You can now edit the URL of any favorite in the Favorites menu or the Favorites Bar. You can use this to update the location of a site that has moved, or to create Bookmarklets in the favorites bar.”

Comment: Great news. I hope it comes to the stable release channel soon.

Answer (score 0):

There is a 3rd-party application called EdgeManage that allows you to manually add a favorite based upon its URL, just like you are describing

Take a look, if you like at: http://www.emmet-gray.com/Articles/EdgeManage.html

PS: I am the author of this software...